# How to get only token Id from card info using flutter stripe?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-stripe

I am trying to make a **token-id** from card information like card number, month, year, and CVC.
This could be possible by the stripe_payment package with the given code:

```
StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
 CardFormPaymentRequest())
 .catchError((e) {
 print('ERROR ${e.toString()}');
 }).then((PaymentMethod paymentMethod) async {
  final CreditCard testCard =  CreditCard(
  number: paymentMethod.card.number,
  expMonth: paymentMethod.card.expMonth,
  expYear: paymentMethod.card.expYear
 );

 StripePayment.createTokenWithCard(testCard).then((token) {
  print(token.tokenId);
  });
 });
```

But the problem is flutter Stripe_payment package is may be converted to flutter_stripe and this code is not working for flutter_stripe.
There is method related flutter_stripe action like **`Future<PaymentMethod> createPaymentMethod(...)`;**
**But here is the problem there is no usage or code example of this function anywhere.**
**So, could anyone please help me to provide resources for getting token id with card info using flutter stripe package.**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check out the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_stripe/latest/flutter_stripe/Stripe/createPaymentMethod.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. But are there any visual or video resources to make or understand the whole code example? Thanks.